# ReactJS: Fetch: parsing json into multiple objects

Tags: json, reactjs, ag-grid-react

I'm a .NET developer building my first ReactJS / AgGrid application, and I have a WEB API returning JSON based on the following:

```
public class CarbonCostsView
{
    public DateTime TradeDate { get; set; }
    public Int16 HourEnding { get; set; }
    public List<CarbonCosts> CarbonCosts { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to parse the returned JSON into three objects but do not know how. Ultimately, the first two elements (TradeDate & HourEnding) will be concatenated into a header message..

The JSON looks like this:

```
{  
   "tradeDate":"2019-04-02T00:00:00",
   "hourEnding":5,
   "carbonCosts":[  
      {  
         "id":101,
         "displayName":"Delta 1X0",
         "tradeDate":"2019-04-02T00:00:00",
         "hourEnding":5,
         "manMin":10.410000,
         "base":7.380000,
         "db":null,
         "pag":null
      },
      {  
         "id":102,
         "displayName":"Delta 1X1",
         "tradeDate":"2019-04-02T00:00:00",
         "hourEnding":5,
         "manMin":7.120000,
         "base":5.230000,
         "db":null,
         "pag":null
      }
  ]
}
```

And here's the JS representing the ReactJS / AgGrid.

```
const columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "Plant", field: "plantName", width: 120, rowGroup: true, sortable: true, filter: true },
    { headerName: "Man Min", field: "manMin", width: 80 },
    { headerName: "Base", field: "base", width: 100 },
    { headerName: "+DB", field: "db", width: 100 },
    { headerName: "+PAG", field: "pag", width: 100 },
    { headerName: "+RA", field: "ra", width: 100 },
];

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            columnDefs: columnDefs,
            header: {}
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:53884/api/OperationalCosts')
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(rowData => this.setState({ rowData }))
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.rowData);
        return (
            <div
                className="ag-theme-balham"
                style={{
                    height: '700px',
                    width: '1000px'
                }}
            >
                <h1> Carbon Costs</h1>

                <AgGridReact
                    columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                    rowData={this.state.rowData}>
                </AgGridReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I suspect that the "magic" I'm looking for happens here? That somewhere in this section I can break out JSON into the three discrete objects?

```
.then(result => result.json())
.then(rowData => this.setState({ rowData }))
```

Comment: You're on the right track. Keep going. Your state is an object itself. So you can do smt like `.setState({obj1: value, obj2: value, obj3: value })`

Comment: .then(result => result.json())
.then(rowData =>{ 
// do your magic here...

this.setState({ rowData :updatedRowData}}))

Comment: if you wish you can destruct your response in different objects and then set your state. Have a look here https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like the answer is:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            columnDefs: columnDefs,
            header: {}
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:53884/api/OperationalCosts')
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(foobar => this.setState(
               { TradeDate: foobar.TradeDate,
                 HourEnding: foobar.HourEnding,
                 CarbonCosts: foobar.carbonCosts }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                className="ag-theme-balham"
                style={{
                    height: '700px',
                    width: '1000px'
                }}
            >
                <h1> Carbon Costs</h1>

                <AgGridReact
                    columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                    rowData={this.state.CarbonCosts}>
                </AgGridReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you for pushing me into the correct direction.

(Still feels really awkward: ReactJS - and js overall - are foreign to me)